# getCurrentUser Magic in AppEngine - how does it work?

Tags: google-app-engine

How does Google allow userService.getCurrentUser() to be called without having it passed HttpServletRequest request param? I am looking to extend UserService but it does not allow me to do that easily.

I have created my own authentication mechanism which overlaps UserService so that I can allow Google supported users and users who will login automatically. But I am interested in knowing how can I send the getCurrentUser when called from any function.

This is the current workflow

Request to secure resource -> Filter -> set current user somewhere but I am not sure WHERE so that I can call it from the rest of the application without passing httprequests..

in my code

GetCurrentUser() should return the user set in the filter. Note that I will not be passing the original HttpServletRequest

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After few days of research, we can safely save the session info in the ThreadLocal. This is set in the servlet filter.
[Static ThreadLocal variable in a WebApp - Are there any Security/Performance issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217173/static-threadlocal-variable-in-a-webapp-are-there-any-security-performance-iss)

Since each servlet is executed in a single thread, we can safely call getCurrentUser from the code which then reads from the threadlocal.

Caveat though. Threads are recycled. So you can get a thread which has threadlocal set for a different user. You have to make sure that it is reset everytime.